# Missing Macintosh drive after running recovery mode

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, disk-utility, recovery

I’m hoping someone can help me. I’ve had to run a recovery mode on my Mac air and when I tried to reinstall the OSX it cannot find the Macintosh HD. I’ve tried to repair the disk0s2 with no success. Can anyone help please?? Thx

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are **very** lo resolution images and impossible to read. All we can tell is that it looks like Disk Utility. If you can upload some better pics that would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a backup of your data? If you don't that's the first thing you want to make before doing anything else. Then you should be able to erase the disk and reinstall macOS.

Comment: Jena: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to reinstall the OS X without first saving any data?